# How to update the size of motion.svg?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, framer-motion

How to update the size of motion.svg?

I have a regular DIV ("maskElement" in my store) that contains a motion.svg element, that in turn contains some rect elements wrapped in SVG g Container.
I need to update my svg element to see all the rect elements. I set the state in a callback hook but the height of my svg element is still 100 even though I see my state change.
I'm using useObserver hook from mobx-lite

```
export interface SVGContainerProps {
    store: myStore;
}

export default function SVGContainer(props: SVGContainerProps): ReactElement {
    const {
        store,
    } = props;

    const [height, setHeight] = useState<number>(100);

    const useSVGRef = useCallback((svg: SVGSVGElement) => {
        const bbox = svg.getBBox();

        console.log('height:', bbox.height);

        setHeight(bbox.height);
    }, [])

    return useObserver(() => (
        <motion.svg
            ref={useSVGRef}
            className={cssSvgContainer}
            dragConstraints={{ current: store.maskElement }}
            dragMomentum={false}
            drag={true}
            whileTap={{ cursor: 'grabbing' }}
            style={{ height: height}}
        >
            {store.items.map((item, index) => (
                <SVGRect
                    key={item.id}
                    item={item}
                    x={0}
                    y={index * 10}
                />
            ))}
        </motion.svg>
    ));
}

const cssSvgContainer = cx(
    cssPointerEventsAll,
    cssAbsolute,
    cssBottom(0),
    cssRight(0),
    cssBorder,
    cssBorderWidth1,
);
```

Comment: svg has a height property, if I pass the height to that it works >.<